# Domain redirect independent of http/https with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I'm trying to redirect my domain with mod_rewrite, but I have some problems with it.

I want to redirect following requests:

```
mydomain.tld [redirect to] www.mydomain.tld
mydomain.tld/xxx.html [redirect to] www.mydomain.tld/xxx.html
mydomain.tld/categorie [redirect to] www.mydomain.tld/categorie
```

so all requests without www in front of the domain must redirect to www.mydomain.tld/...

My special feature must be - it should no matter if the request is http or https:

```
https://mydomain.tld [redirect to] https://www.mydomain.tld
https://mydomain.tld/xxx.html [redirect to] https://www.mydomain.tld/xxx.html
https://mydomain.tld/categorie [redirect to] https://www.mydomain.tld/categorie
```

Here is what I've already tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.tld\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But now I don't know how to do the redirect for https requests.
It would be great when you can help me.
Thanks

**EDIT**

The following solution works fine for me, BUT is it possible to make it easier or to combine the first 2 lines of the 2 blocks?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading mod_rewrite docs one is tempted to use %{REQUEST_SCHEME} but this is not reliable.

But we can define an equivalent ourselves like this:

```
# Prepare our REQUEST_SCHEME workaround, use with %{ENV:REQUEST_SCHEME}
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* - [E=REQUEST_SCHEME:http]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule .* - [E=REQUEST_SCHEME:https]

# Redirect mydomain.tld to www.mydomain.tld preserving http[s] scheme
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:REQUEST_SCHEME}://www.mydomain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what I want :/

Answer (score 0):

Enhancing aexl's suggestion for CloudFlare users:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule .* - [E=REQUEST_SCHEME:http]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"https"'
RewriteRule .* - [E=REQUEST_SCHEME:https]
```

Answer (score 0):

ok?

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on
RewriteRule .* - [E=SSL:s]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%{ENV:SSL}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```